# Iterating over data body rows only

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am using this  `For` loop to iterate over the rows of the table. `r` is a `ListRow` object and `d` is `Scripting.Dictionary`:

```
For Each r In Sheet20.ListObjects("Table24").ListRows
    d(r.Range.Cells(0, 2).Value) = 1
Next
```

But this always takes header row and omits the last row. How can I modify this to iterate over all the data rows leaving out header row?

Comment: ["*The `ListRows` object returned does not include the header, total, or Insert rows.*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listrows#remarks)

Comment: For some reason in my case everything is shifted up by one row, so header row is added to the `d` and last row isn't. I suppose my error lies in this line `d(r.Range.Cells(0, 2).Value) = 1`...

Comment: Start with `Debug.Print r.Address`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I think that rows start with index `1` and this is why if I change `d(r.Range.Cells(0, 2).Value) = 1` to `d(r.Range.Cells(1, 2).Value) = 1` it ommits the header row. I think now everything works.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for the hint using `r.Address`!

Comment: You can reference the second cell (column) of a list row with `r.Range.Cells(2)`, or shorter with `r.Range(2)`. If for some unknown reason you want to supply both parameters, you can use `r.Range.Cells(1, 2)` where `1` means the first (and only) row.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate trough **rows** of the databody from a listobject, you may use the collection **rows** from object databody itself. Just as example:

[image]

This table is called `Table1`.

```
Sub test()
Dim TT As ListObject
Dim vRow As Range

Set TT = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

For Each vRow In TT.DataBodyRange.Rows
    Debug.Print vRow.Address
Next vRow

Set TT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

```
$A$6:$B$6
$A$7:$B$7
$A$8:$B$8
$A$9:$B$9
```

Notice the code iterated just once for each row of the data, **excluding** headers...

In your case, not tested but something kind of like this should work:

```
Dim vRow As Range

For Each vRow In Sheet20.ListObjects("Table24").DataBodyRange.Rows
    d(vRow.Cells(1, 2).Value) = 1
Next vRow
```

> [ListObject.DataBodyRange property
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange)

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are absolutely right, My bad. I've corrected it, Thanks!